# Short circuiting SQL count function

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets assume we are using count function to test a range condition in SQL, something like:

```
select * from table1 where (select count(*) from ...) >= 2
```

How can we have our SQL written so that the count function is kind of short circuited meaning that since having at least two records satisfies our condition, when the database finds the first two records it doesn't continue with finding other records to be included in the count, hence improving the performance dramatically?
the inner select that does the counting is a complicated one hence I'm trying to somehow tell database it doesn't have to count every record.

Comment: Please provide more information about the query.

Comment: I updated the problem description. Please let me know if it is still not clear. Thanks

Comment: You may wish to read about SQL's `HAVING` clause. Without knowing what's in your inner `SELECT COUNT(*)`  it's impossible to say whether it will work for you.

Comment: Well I ahem tried group by and having and it has the same performance issue. Does database do the short circuiting that I talked about when using having? That is it stops counting as soon as it finds two records in each group?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to give a [MRE] including an example table with sample data (as DDL/DML statements that we can copy/paste) and a complete query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table1 where (select count(*) c from table2 
                                             where table1_pk = table2_fk 
                                               and rownum < 3) = 2
```

The rownum will cause a stop once two matching records are found.